# Visual studio 2019 after last update no longer showing the Data context class in the select menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

Edit:
Updating Visual studio 2019 to Version 16.6.3 solves the problem

Visual studio 2019 after last update no longer showing the Data context class,

- if i try to add new controller by selecting the MVC template as shown
  in the image
- if found that if my  Db class extend DbContext it will work and show
  up in the dialog
- if my DB class extend IdentityDbContext it will not show in the
  [Data context class]

to reproduce the problem just create a new MCV based on .net core 3.1  the problem will be there

[image]

Comment: Updating Visual studio 2019 to Version 16.6.3 solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As time being the best work around for this problem is to create another db context which extend DbContext

- First create a class name it WorkAroundContext.cs with the following code

  ```
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
    namespace YourNameSpace
   {

     public partial class WorkAroundContext : DbContext
     {
       public WorkAroundContext(DbContextOptions<WorkAroundContext> options)
             : base(options)
       { }
     }
   }
  ```
- then in your startup.cs add the following code

  ```
    services.AddDbContext<WorkAroundContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conn));
  ```
- Use the WorkAroundContext to create your controller
- Finally edit the generated files and change WorkAroundContext to ApplicationDbContext

Edit:
Updating Visual studio 2019 to Version 16.6.3 solves the problem

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded VS and this problem has gone away. I was running Version 16.6.2 prior to upgrading.